# Open a properties file from a class in a Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, properties-file

I'm using Eclipse for EE Developer.

I need to access to a properties file (db.properties) from a class's method (DBQuery.java).
The class is located inside a package inside the src folder.
For the properties file i tried almost everything that i could find over the net to make it work, but looks like i can't.
The properties file is located inside the WebContent folder, and i'll add the code with which i'm trying to load this file:

```
public class DBQuery {

    public static String create_DB_string(){

        //the db connection string
        String connString = "";

        try{
            Properties props = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("db.properties");

            props.load(fis);
            fis.close();

                /* creating connString using props.getProperty("String"); */

         }
       catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
        }       
        return connString;
    } 
}
```

So my question is, where to put the properties file, and which is the correct way to load it?

Comment: That's the correct way to read/load it; not the correct way to close I/O resources. And you have to make sure the `.properties` file is in the _classpath_. Are you using Maven?

Comment: If ur file db.properties is inside the package then u need to mention that.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ Ok, thanks fr replyin. I closed the FileInputStream, i've added the folder that contains db.properties in the classpath, but still not working.
I'm not using maven btw, whatis this?

Comment: If you would be using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) it's easier to advice you since everyone knows the directory structure. The answer is the same: the `.properties` must be in the _classpath_. Try to copy the file alone and play with it until you get the results, then put it inside a directory and change your code (because in that case you need also to include the directory where the file is at)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this propertie file within your java package for example com/test and use following:

getClass().getResourceAsStream( "com/test/myfile.propertie");

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks dude, i actually make it work using 

"InputStream fis = DBQuery.class.getResourceAsStream("db.properties");"

thanks again :)